# Can you alter nutritional properties of beans and other ingredients using diastatic malt?

Tags: food-science, nutrient-composition, chemistry

I was reading about brewers' spent grain the other day and its nutritional profile (high protein and fiber content, no carbs) and how it's obtained. Would something similar be possible with beans and other ingredients? As in, that carbohydrates end up in the cooking liquid/pseudo-wort and I end up with carb-free beans if I were to mash them?

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/13675/67